# Javascript Syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I am trying to set a google tracking event on Javascript store finder for a client of mine. I already have a event tracking on "submit button" which works fine. Every store on the map has a link for more information. I am trying to setup an event for the "More information" link so that it shows which store has the most clicks.

For some reason I get an error as soon as I past the Google event tracking code using OnClick event inside my link. Below is the section which has the store details:

```
 var contentString =
    '<div id="content" style="height:150px"><div id="bodyContent"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 14px">' +
    location[0] + '</span><br /><br />' + location[1] + '<br />' + location[2] + ', ' + location[3] + ' ' + 
    location[4] + '<br /><br /><a href="contractordetail.aspx?id=' + 
    location[8] + '&zip=' + $("#ctl00_Body_ctl00_zip").val() +'" >More information</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' + location[1] + '+' + location[2] + '+' + location[3] + '+' + location[4] + '&hl=en&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&z=4" target="_blank">Get Directions</a><br /></div></div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString, maxWidth: 300 });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

The above code works fine, but when I try to put Onclick event, I get an error:

```
    var contentString =
    '<div id="content" style="height:150px"><div id="bodyContent"><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 14px">' +
    location[0] + '</span><br /><br />' + location[1] + '<br />' + location[2] + ', ' + location[3] + ' ' + 
    location[4] + '<br /><br /><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Contractor Search', eventAction: 'Submit', eventLabel: 'Search Contractors'});" href="contractordetail.aspx?id=' + 
    location[8] + '&zip=' + $("#ctl00_Body_ctl00_zip").val() +'" >More information</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=' + location[1] + '+' + location[2] + '+' + location[3] + '+' + location[4] + '&hl=en&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&z=4" target="_blank">Get Directions</a><br /></div></div>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString, maxWidth: 300 });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Notice that the second code has a onclick event on my "More Information" link. This were I get an error everytime I try to use an onclick event. I used single code around it which removed the error, but then the search didnt work.

Any help is highly appreciated!
Thanks,

Comment: just escape your `'`-es with `\'`

Comment: Thank  you so much. Escaping single quotes worked.  Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I had to escape all single quotes inside event tracking block code. Thank you vp_arth